# Is it ok to call super.superClassMethod() in a constructor in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor

I was taught that it is bad practice to call an overridable method in a constructor. What if I explicitly call the method of the parent class? Something like:

```
public class SuperClass{
    public void method(){
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    Subclass(){
        super.method();
    }
}
```

Could still consistency issues be present? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: There is no inherent problem with doing this.

Comment: I disagree with @AndyTurner. There's no guarantee that the called method does not in turn call another method that might be overwritten and cause problems.